# CD / DVD Catalog Software For Linux

Tags: linux, optical-media

I'm looking for some Linux cataloging software so I can simply label my disks with a number and be able to punch that into my catalog to see whats on the disc.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You can try **[GCstar](http://www.gcstar.org/index.en.php)**.

> **GCstar** is a free open source application for managing your collections. Detailed information on each item can be automatically retrieved from the internet and you can store additional data, such as the location or who you've lent it to. You may also search and filter your collection by many criteria.

Answer (score 0):

- http://sourceforge.net/softwaremap/trove_list.php?form_cat=783
- Gnome catalog, cddb, Katalog
- If "VisualCD" works on Wine, that is a great option too.

HTH